# MVC EDMX Codebehind is using ObjectContext vs DBContext

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am new to EF.  I have a separate Project for my Models.  I have EF 4.3.1.0 installed.  I see that the base class of the Context is ObjectContext and not DbContext.  This becomes an issue when i scaffold my Controller in my front end project where in the Edit action it makes a call to

```
context.Entry(status).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

but Entry is not known.  I found that Entry is new with DbContext.

How do I have the generated code generate the right stuff?

This is a DB First project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must apply the [EF 4.x DbContext Generator](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7812b04c-db36-4817-8a84-e73c452410a2) to your EDMX model in Visual Studio. You can install the generator template from the Visual Studio extension manager.

When you have installed the template follow the steps under point 4 in this post:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/15/ef-4-1-model-amp-database-first-walkthrough.aspx

(Replace "ADO.NET DbContext Generator" in the post by the installed "EF 4.x DbContext Generator" which is the up-to-date and renamed version for EF 4.3.1)

The template will generate POCO classes and a derived `DbContext` from your EDMX model.

Comment: I have tried to do as you have outlined.  I find that while the new context is created based on the DbContext, the old definition of the context still remains in the edmx codebehind designer.cs file.  As a result all my objects/tables are coming up with errors of being redefined when I compile.

Comment: @Jeff: That's strange. When you use "Add code generation item..." from the EDMX designer surface, the designer.cs file should actually be emptied (except an autogenerated comment). Do you have everything in the same project/assembly? Maybe ask a new question about the problem, I don't know how this mess could occur.

Comment: My model is in a separate project.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this article "[Using DbContext To Query Model-First/Database-First EDMX Models](http://alexandrebrisebois.wordpress.com/2012/10/14/using-dbcontext-to-query-model-firstdatabase-first-edmx-models/)" this will allow you to continue using your existing code without making any changes.